# How to open application's location permission settings directly in React Native

Tags: react-native, permissions, settings, react-native-navigation

**REACTNATIVE :** Currently using **Linking.openSettings()** to open my application settings page.

Now, I want to open the app permission screen directly, which is inside the App settings to enable permissions like Location, Storage etc., in both Android and iOS using REACT NATIVE.

Any possibilities? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you found any solution to it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Shortly it's possible,***

For IOS operating system, Try below,

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native'
Linking.openURL('app-settings:')
```

But Android not working with Linking,We should add two dependency,

> npm install --save react-native-device-info

> npm install react-native-intent-launcher

As a result,

```
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';
import IntentLauncher, { IntentConstant } from 'react-native-intent-launcher'
const package= DeviceInfo.getBundleId();
const openAppSettings = () => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    Linking.openURL('app-settings:')
  } else {
    IntentLauncher.startActivity({
      action: 'android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS',
      data: 'package:' + package
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**ANDROID ONLY:**

I found a solution based [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76286730/7133482) from Android devs; and then I tried with React Native.

I use the `react-native-permissions` library for this purpose.

With that in mind, we **must** first request `'android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission, so that we can redirect our user to ask for Background location, which the user can only change directly in the App settings.

My app has one screen asking for the `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`. Then, on the next screen, I request `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission.

In React Native, the code will be the following:

```js
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { PERMISSIONS, RESULTS, check, request } from 'react-native-permissions';


if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  // first ask the FINE_LOCATION permission, and then check
  const androidLocationPermissionRequest = await request(
    PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
  );
  const isGranted = androidLocationPermissionRequest === RESULTS.GRANTED;

  if (isGranted) {
    // This function will redirect the user to YOUR APP "Location Permission" page
    // instead of showing the prompt (default behaviour) because it is how Android currently works to give bg location.
    // so the user can change to "Always allow" etc.
    await request(PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION);
  }
}
```